# Laravel 5.1 Routes.Php Thinks I Am Not Authorized?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

so I have an ajax call to a contoller which is logging me in, I know this is working because of `Auth::check($user)` and the returned cookie data, such as the laravel session cookie.

However, my problem is in my `routes.php`, I still can't get to the authorized only pages, and keep hitting the `welcome` view.

My routes.php:

```
use App\punsmodel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('google' ,  [
'as' => 'verify.index',
'uses' => 'verify@verifyIdToken'
]);

if (Auth::guest()) {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
} else {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function ()    {
           return view('mainview');
        });

         Route::get('mainview', function ()    {
           return view('mainviewMolly');
        });
    });
}
```

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Email;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google_Client; 
use Auth;
use App\User;
class verify extends Controller
{

    public function verifyIdToken(Request $request)
    {
         $user = User::where('name', 'Molly')->first();
         Auth::login($user);
         if (Auth::check($user))
         {
             return response()->json(['Logged In' => "Yes!"]);
         }
    }
}
```

So I do an ajax request to the above controller, which works as I get the json response that says I was logged in, however then when I refresh the homepage, I still get the welcome page not the `mainview`. Why is this the case?

My ajax request:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://mysite.come/google",
  data: { email: profile.getEmail(),
     id: id_token }
}).done(function() {
       $("#google").text("You Are Indeed Who I Thought You Were! :)");
     }).fail(function() {
       $("#google").text("You Are Not Who I Thought You Were, Please Go Away!");
       setTimeout(function() {
         window.location = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random";
       //}, 4000);
       }, 9999999000);
     })
```

Comment: Can you put your JS ajax call?

Comment: @PeterPan666 done! :)

Comment: I don't think it's actually advised to check for an authenticated session outside the routing scope - this is best done inside the scope. A simple `return view(Auth::check() ? 'mainview' : 'welcome')` should suffice.